# How to loop through the switch statement without the while(true) loop

Tags: java

So i have been coding an array calculator, but i have gotten to a point where i want to shorten the code, so what i'm trying to do is find a way to break out of the `while` loop so i can have a single block where it prints the results indenpendent from the operator i choose to do the calc, but i can't seen to figure out a way to break out of the `while(true)` loop whitout it telling that the statement is unreachable for any code that comes after it, so my goals are:

1 - Be able to print the result of the operations outside the `while(true)` loop.
2 - Find a way to not use the `while(true)` loop if possible (I saw many people complaining about the readability of the code using it).

This is the current code state:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Creates scanner for user input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Creates variables to define the size of the array and the value to make the operations
        int arraySize = 0, arrayCalc = 0;

        //Gets the size of the array
        System.out.println("Please enter the size of your array:");
        arraySize = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        //Repeats if array size is zero
        while (arraySize <= 0) {
            System.out.println("The size of your array is too small, please set a bigger value:");
            arraySize = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
        }

        //Gets the values of the array
        int[] array = new int[arraySize];
        System.out.println("Please enter the values for your array:");
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please, put the char compatible with the operation you want to do:");

        //Loop in case operator is not valid
        while(true) {

            //Sets the operator
            String operation = input.nextLine();

            switch (operation) {

                case "+":

                    //Addition operation
                    System.out.println("Please enter what value you would like to add to your array:");
                    arrayCalc = input.nextInt();
                    while (arrayCalc < 0) {
                        System.out.println("The value you have entered is too small, please use a bigger number:");
                        arrayCalc = input.nextInt();
                    }

                    //Makes the operation
                    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                        array[i] = array[i] + arrayCalc;
                    }

                    //Prints the operation
                    System.out.print("Those are your numbers after the addition: ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize- 1; i++) {
                        System.out.print(array[i] + ", ");
                        if (i == arraySize - 2) {
                            System.out.println(array[i + 1] + ".");
                        }
                    }
                    System.exit(0);

                case "-":

                    //Subtraction operation
                    System.out.println("Please enter what value you would like to subtract to your array:");
                    arrayCalc = input.nextInt();
                    while (arrayCalc < 0) {
                        System.out.println("The value you have entered is too small, please use a bigger number:");
                        arrayCalc = input.nextInt();
                    }

                    //Makes the operation
                    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                        array[i] = array[i] - arrayCalc;
                    }

                    //Prints the operation
                    System.out.print("Those are your numbers after the subtraction: ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize - 1; i++) {
                        System.out.print(array[i] + ", ");
                        if (i == arraySize - 2) {
                            System.out.println(array[i + 1] + ".");
                        }
                    }
                    System.exit(0);

                case "*":

                    //Multiplication operation
                    System.out.println("Please enter what value you would like to multiply to your array:");
                    arrayCalc = input.nextInt();
                    while (arrayCalc < 0) {
                        System.out.println("The value you have entered is too small, please use a bigger number:");
                        arrayCalc = input.nextInt();
                    }

                    //Makes the operation
                    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                        array[i] = array[i] * arrayCalc;
                    }

                    //Prints the operation
                    System.out.print("Those are your numbers after the multiplication: ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize - 1; i++) {
                        System.out.print(array[i] + ", ");
                        if (i == arraySize - 2) {
                            System.out.print(array[i + 1] + ".");
                        }
                    }
                    System.exit(0);

                case "/":

                    //Division operation
                    System.out.println("Please enter what value you would like to divide to your array:");
                    arrayCalc = input.nextInt();
                    while (arrayCalc < 0) {
                        System.out.println("The value you have entered is too small, please use a bigger number:");
                        arrayCalc = input.nextInt();
                    }

                    //Makes the operation
                    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                        array[i] = array[i] / arrayCalc;
                    }

                    //Prints the operation
                    System.out.print("Those are your numbers after the division: ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize - 1; i++) {
                        System.out.print(array[i] + ", ");
                        if (i == arraySize - 2) {
                            System.out.print(array[i + 1] + ".");
                        }
                    }
                    System.exit(0);

                default:

                    //Exception if input is not a proper operator
                    System.out.println("That's not a valid operator! try \"+\" \"-\" \"*\" or \"/\".");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Java offers labeled statements. You could have something like `mainLoop: while (true) { switch (operation) { case '*': ... break mainLoop; ...` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html  . But, personally, I prefer to have something like `boolean operatorValid = false; ... while ( ! operatorValid) { ...`.

Comment: Heya. Is there a particular reason you are using System.exit(0) over the keyword break?

Comment: @Xenorosth yes, basically because if i try to use break inside the while loop it doesn't stops the loop but execute what's on default and stops the code, i tried a bunch of ways to work arround it but i can't find a way to jump out of the while loop using the break that's not labeled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of better ways to program this, as there is a lot of repeat code, which is likely complicating this, for the sake of keeping the answer focused, I will keep code changes minimal.

Using break will not go to the loop in this case because switch/case is block that can be broken, but there are a few helpful things that will not make it needed.

Option 1: Create a new condition to stop while(true)

Instead of using while(true), think about the condition in which you want the loop to stop. Since you want to stop it once a valid execution happens, create a new boolean variable above the loop that tracks the validity of an execution. Before the loop, initialize a boolean and set it to true. Then where you do System.exit(0), replace that with setting the boolean to false. Psuedo-ish-code below.

```
boolean notFinished = true; 
while(notFinished){
   String operation = input.nextLine();
   switch(operation){
       case "+":
           //Do addition things here.
           notFinished = false;  //Stops the loop. 
           break;
       //... other cases
   }
}
```

Option 2: Swap out switch case for if statements.

Since switch/case would eat the break, if/else if may be a better option for you. Psuedo-ish-code below.

```
while(true){
   String operation = input.nextLine();
   if(operation.charAt(0) == '+'){  //This gets the first character of your string
       //Do addition things here.
           
       break; // Now breaks the loop.
   }
   //... other if statements for other operations
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! i did the `while(!validOperator)` in the last change i made in the code, i compacted it a lot recently and made it easier to read. I didn't used the `if` statement cause i felt like the switch would make easier to read and because it's something that i wasn't used with, so this was mostly a test so i could understand those statements better, there's probably a lot of things that can be improved, but with the help you guys gave me it's already one of the easiest codes to read ever wrote, thanks again for the tips!